# MVC4 oauth facebook accessing User & Friend Permissions:

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

Using the new mvc4 now gives us access to use facebook oauth otb.

I have created a new app within facebook and have set some extra requirements around asking permission for the users email address/location & birthday.

I have saved the changes within fb and when clicking on the preview auth dialog I can see the extra permissions I want displayed within the preview window.

When I try authenticate against facebook I am not asked if I give permission to the extra fields I setup within facebook.

Is there something else within my mvc application I need to change to pass these extra requirements to facebook?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have to write your own custom provider. If so, you should look at 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx
and 
http://blog.mrroa.com/post/30454808112/asp-net-custom-linkedin-oauth-provider

What I do is :
In `AccountController` :
 - I add using Facebook; (`facebook.dll` from www.csharpsdk.org)
also in `AccountController`, find in `ExternalLoginCallback`:

Here, i use the facebook c# sdk to ask for extra permissions before invoking `CreateOrUpdateAccount`.

I don't think this is the best solution but it works.

Comment: I've followed rroa custom provider and tried to get more user info from LinkedIn in response using custom provider but it doesnt return me more info ever. For example, I changed this URL `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,industry,summary)` to new URL `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,headline,industry,summary)` to get user email as well but it never returns me email of user. Any suggestion how can I get more user info?

Comment: OK. After searching a lot, I got a solution [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/permission-scope-request-token-query-not-working?page=1). We need to add scope at this line `RequestTokenEndpoint =
                            new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress",
                            HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest)`. One can add more and more scope to get more data

Comment: Have a look at this solution from this post http://tinyurl.com/aherzvm :

Update your NuGet package in your MVC4 Internet project.

DotNetOpenAuthCore. It will automatically update all dependencies.

Now result.UserName will contain the email adress instead of your name.

Answer (score 1):

> I have created a new app within facebook and have set some extra requirements around asking permission for the users email address/location & birthday.
>
> I have saved the changes within fb and when clicking on the preview auth dialog I can see the extra permissions I want displayed within the preview window.
>
> When I try authenticate against facebook I am not asked if I give permission to the extra fields I setup within facebook.

This sounds like you are another one that’s confused about what *[Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals)* actually do. (The permission fields in your app settings apply to those only!)

*Authenticated Referrals* come into play, when a user clicks on any link redirecting to your app on Facebook.

If you are doing the login yourself, however – you have to ask for the permissions you want using the `scope` parameter.

Comment: Hey @CBroe I have used the js sdk in the past so I am aware of needing to add the scope details. So the default one provided by out of the box doesnt allow me to add scope settings. Do I need to create a custom Facebook client that allows me to add the scope details in?

Comment: I don’t know what’s “default” and “out of the box” in your development environment …

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you use ILSpy on the FacebookClient class that ships with MVC 4 you can see that the MS code simply doesn't request the email info even though the underlying DotNetOpenAuth classes support it.

You therefore need to implement your own FacebookClient class which does pretty much the same thing but adds in the email address to the requested items. I am attempting this myself right now and hope to have it working soon.