# Permissions for application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I set `User & Friend Permissions` on my application, to get user email on website. I get this info when I click `Preview Login Dialog`:

> THIS APP WILL RECEIVE:
>
> ```
> Your basic info
> Your email address (xyz@xyz.com)
> Your birthday
> Your relationship details
> Your photos
> ```

when I tried to log in on my website, application needs only this information:

> THIS APP WILL RECEIVE:
>
> ```
> Your basic info
> ```

Why? Why doesn't the main application have the same permissions as the preview?

Regards

EDIT:

I'm using Auth from this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc - and code has not changed in my project.
Honestly, I don't want to change authorization methods, because I also want to provide Twitter login, and this mechanism is perfect for me. 
I just want to add for Facebook "scope=email,publish_stream".

I discovered, that when I put this query manually when my website redirect me to facebook application (`&scope=email,publish_stream`), everything works perfect. Is there any solution to do this on back-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

If you are using this tutorial : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Insert in your 
`Package manager console`
 this command `update-package DotNetOpenAuth.Core`

**Now your application will automatically ask for user e-mail - you don't have to change anything**.
Here you will find result - `result.UserName`

Answer (score 2):

> The app detail page in the App Center displays the
>   permissions required for new users. It can be considered a version of
>   the Login Dialog in this capacity, making it easy for new users to
>   install your app directly from the App Center. You can configure the
>   set of permissions your app requires in the Settings > Permissions
>   tab.

*Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#authorization*

So, these permission settings only apply when you've got an app in the App Center to configure, which case it is useful to:

- show what permissions the user will be asked *before* the user decides to use the app,
- avoid any additional Login Dialog.

Because your app don't (I guess) figure in the App Center, you have to ask for permissions using the usual way: from the code. To do so, read: [How to use user permissions with Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690067/how-to-use-user-permissions-with-facebook-c-sharp-sdk)

**Edit:** 
Forget about the App Center for now. It is the last step you should do. The App Center gathers great and famous apps only, which all work perfectly and that Facebook employees need to accept:

> Not all apps will appear in the App Center, and we reserve the right
>   to remove apps that do not meet a high quality bar. Once you’ve created your app detail page, we’ll review it and your app to make sure it meets our eligibility, submission, and quality guidelines.

So, asking for your app to appear on the App Center really is the **last thing** you should think about.

Comment: thanks for reply. But explanation about C# sdk and passing additional infos are still not clear for me - have you some another links about it?

Comment: And how can I go to AppCenter? And is this center solve my problem?

Comment: No, forget about the App Center. I've updated my post with more information about that. What you have to do now is to complete the code you made to login a user with the right permissions. Before I give you some code that explains this, why don't you show us the code you already implemented to make a user login on your website?

Comment: Please, look at edit - I added info about code. Generaly it is the same as in tutorial asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Comment: OK, good! The OAuth Providers with MVC 4 doesn't itself make it possible to add permissions. You have to pluggin a custom OAuth/OpenID provider. The question you are wondering about and the answer you need are provided on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126253/mvc4-oauth-facebook-accessing-user-friend-permissions.

Comment: Please, look at my new post - I searched user e-mail, and I found it :) I tried this solution on my 2 projects, and it works perfectly. Anyway, big thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Stéphane Bruckert is right, the permissions you add in the settings page of your app is only applicable when a user visits your website through app center.

To ask for permission from within your site you've to add those permissions in the `scope` parameter of your `Login URL`.

```
fb = new FacebookClient();

    var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
    {

        client_id = "app_id",

        redirect_uri = "http://www.example.com/Facebook.aspx",

        response_type = "code",

        scope = "email,publish_stream" // Add other permissions as needed

    });
Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
```

Here's good tutorial for using [Facebook C# SDK](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html).

For your question in the comments, you can publish your app in the app center by filling all the details on the App Details page and finally submitting it for review.